# Python Datetime Strptime Error: '-' is a bad directive in format '%-m-%-d-%y %-H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, datetime

I know that there have been similar questions asked, but they seemed to have to do with the way datetime deals (or doesn't deal) with timezones.

The setup is a little complicated, and probably not relevant to the problem, but I thought it was important to include the code as is, so a little background:

I've got a dictionary of arrays. Each of these arrays represents an "attempt" by the same person, but taking place at different times. Ultimately I'm going to be looking for the earliest of these dates. This may be a bit of a roundabout solution, but I'm converting all of the dates to datetime objects, finding the earliest and then just using that index to pull out the first attempt:

Here's what the code looks like to setup that array of attempt datetimes:

```
for key in duplicates_set.keys():
    attempt_dates = [datetime.strptime(attempt['Attempt Date'], "%-m-%-d-%y %-H:%M:%S") for attempt in duplicates_set[key]]
```

Here's the format of what one of the original date strings looks like:

`12-5-2016  3:27:58 PM`

What I'm getting back is:

```
ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%-m-%d-%y %-H:%M:%S'
```

I assume that's referring to the dashes placed before the 'm', 'd' and 'H' because they're non-zero-padded decimals. Why is it telling me that?

Comment: Presumably you wanted `%m-%d-%y %H:%M:%S` ? https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: @jtbandes, `%-H` actually *does* have meaningful usage in GNU strftime -- it differs from `%H` in that it skips leading zeros.

Comment: "Presumably" was too harsh, but I can't edit my comment anymore...

Comment: BTW, `%-m%-d` is a really bad idea. How can you tell the difference between `1/11` and `11/1`, if you render both as `111`?

Comment: Yes, in this case, the `%-m` and `%-H` were intentional, though I see how it's confusing, as the date strings also include dashes. I've gotten it to work without using them now, though. Thank you both!

Comment: And to answer the question above, I'm converting towards a datetime object, not into a string, but also there is a dash in the string that's not part of one of the directives.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`%-*` -- to skip padding -- is a GNU libc extension. It's not part of POSIX strftime, and thus not guaranteed to be portable to systems where your time-formatting calls aren't eventually backed by GNU's `strftime` C library function.

[The Python `datetime` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) explicitly specifies the format strings it supports, and this extension is not given. Thus, while this is supported in GNU date and GNU `strftime()`, it isn't available in Python `datetime`.

Comment: ok, but I have a time format with no 0 padding,
 this answer doesn't look like it provides a solution to how to read this format in python using strptime

Comment: @Veggiet, you don't _need_ a directive to skip padding on the parsing side; it's only needed on the generation side. `datetime.datetime.strptime('2-1-2020 3:14:5', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')` works fine.

Comment: Weirdly, I have been using `%Y-%-m-%-d` with `strftime` just fine. So, I assumed `%Y-%-m-%-d` would work for `strptime`.  It did not, and this produced a hard to find bug.  If it is going to be partially supported, it should probably be fully supported.  Otherwise, you can learn a bug implicitly.  No bueno.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue;
date: 1/9/21

according to:
https://strftime.org/ the correct format would've been "%-d/%-m/%y"
which gave the bad directive error.
"%d-/%m-/%y" didn't work either.

Weirdly enough what worked was "%d/%m/%y".

Comment: %d and %-d are different formats. %-d skips trailing zeros

Comment: This seems to have worked for me as well; by the way in that first example you give, it's unclear if it's month then date or date then month lol.

Comment: Same here, it is really weird that this works, maybe new version is just smarter

Comment: %d worked even though you were only inputting '9' and not '09'?