# '-' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%-m-%-d' - python/django

Tags: python

Trying to convert str to date ,e.g '2017-8-27'

my code:

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
import datetime, collections

date = dt.strptime('2017-8-27', '%Y-%-m-%-d')
```

But I see the following message:

> '-' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%-m-%-d'

And don't understand what is incorrect. How can I solve it?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Look here: https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Comment: Why this question was closed? The question is well formulated, simple and valid. I have the same issue and because somebody close this, i cannot see any solution, and I pretty sure that if I post a similar question, the same people who closed this will close my post or mark as duplicated, it's really annoying.

Comment: Indeed, the question is well posed. DeepSpace is incorrect as the additional dash is due to the non-zero-padded month. The problem is actually with datetime as this formatting will only work in Linux. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191365/python-datetime-strptime-error-is-a-bad-directive-in-format-m-d-y-h

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The % should be followed by a format specifier.

The correct format string is '%Y-%m-%d'

Comment: It isn't. He needs %-m because the month isn't zero-padded.

Comment: Try to run `datetime.strptime('2017-8-27', '%Y-%-m-%d')` and you'll get the following error message: `'-' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%-m-%d'`. The correct format is indeed the one in the answer, i.e `'%Y-%m-%d'`.

Comment: before that I checking if month or day len is 1, if so just prepending 0