# convert string date to another string date

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
y='Monday, December 9, 2019'
```

I want to convert the above string to DD/MM/YYYY I tried

`c=datetime.strptime(y,'%A, %B %-d,%Y')`

so I can then easily convert it but it is giving me `ValueError: '-' is a bad directive in format '%A, %B %-d,%Y` I checked this question
['-' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%-m-%-d' - python/django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45507848/is-a-bad-directive-in-format-y-m-d-python-django?rq=1) but still gives error, is there a way to do this without using `re` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct format is `'%A, %B %d, %Y'` (noticed the removed `-`), and to change it to `DD/MM/YYYY`, the format is `%d-%m-%Y'`

```
from datetime import datetime
y='Monday, December 9, 2019'

#Fixed format
c=datetime.strptime(y,'%A, %B %d, %Y')

#Changed to represent DD/MM/YYYY
print(c.strftime('%d-%m-%Y'))
```

The output will be

```
09-12-2019
```