# Parsing a date with no leading zeros, no space, and no backlash

Tags: python, datetime, leading-zero

Hi I have a string like this: "202082201", which means 2020/8/2 20:01.

This is because every field in the string doesn't have any leading zero.

The task is to turn this string into a date in python. I've tried this code:

```
regex ='%Y%m%d%H%M'
str = "202082201"
date_obj = dt.strptime(str, regex)
date_str = dt.strftime(date_obj, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
print(date_str)
```

But it gives me 2020/08/22 00:01 instead.

Comment: According to the [`strptime` table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63239616/parsing-a-date-with-no-leading-zeros-no-space-and-no-backlash), the `%m` and `%d` tokens require a leading `0`, which `8` and `2` from the input provided is missing.

Comment: Moreover, if you replace `8` with `1`, it will then parse `12` together.  In short, the provided string without leading `0`s for the month and date will result in ambiguous results.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet is to create a custom function to call instead of `strftime()`. Have it take in a datetime object and then spit out the custom string you need.

Example:

```
regex ='%Y%m%d%H%M'
str = "202082201"
date_obj = dt.strptime(str, regex)

date_only_str = f"{date_obj.year}/{date_obj.month}/{date_obj.day}"
time_str = date_obj.strftime('%H:%M')
date_str = f"{date_only_str} {time_str}"

print(date_str)


2020/8/22 00:01
```

Here lines 5-7 can be put into a function if you are going to reuse them.

```
def date_to_string(dt_obj):
    date = f"{dt_obj.year}/{dt_obj.month}/{dt_obj.day}"
    time = dt_obj.strftime('%H:%M')
    return f"{date} {time}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
regex ='%Y%m%d%H%M'
str = "202082201"
date_obj = dt.strptime(str, regex)
date_str = dt.strftime(date_obj, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
print(date_str)
```

If you look at this block of code, the %d directive is zero padded. So if you were to inspect the properties of your date_obj:

```py
>>> regex ='%Y%m%d%H%M'
>>> str = "202082201"
>>> date_obj = dt.strptime(str, regex)
>>> date_str = dt.strftime(date_obj, '%Y/%m/%d %H:%M')
>>> print(date_str)
2020/08/22 00:01
>>> date_obj.hour
0
>>> date_obj.month
8
>>> date_obj.year
2020
>>> date_obj.month
8
>>> date_obj.day
22
>>> date_obj.hour
0
>>> date_obj.minute
1
>>>
```

There [seems](https://strftime.org/) to be a directive for decimal number if you use %-d instead of %d, but there is a note that it depends says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191365/python-datetime-strptime-error-is-a-bad-directive-in-format-m-d-y-h).